# Unable to map/list array taken from YouTube API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to fetch videos from YouTube API, but it seems like whenever I try to fetch them, somehow the map function won't work. (**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**)

The code was successful in fetching array lists from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts), but not from YouTube.

I suspect the problem occurred because the array that YouTube provided was inside an [items] object.

Here are my code:

> **PopularApp.js**
>
> ```
> import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
> import PopularVid from "./components/PopularVid";
> import axios from 'axios';
>
> const PopularApp = () => {
>     const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);
>     const hotVids = video.items;
>     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
>     const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
>     const [vidsPerPage, setVidsPerPage] = useState(10);
>
>     useEffect(() => { //whenever this function runs, it will run this/fetch data from API, neverending loop
>         const fetchPosts = async () => {
>             setLoading();
>             const res = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=12&key=myapikey');
>             setVideo(res.data);
>             setLoading(false);
>         }
>         fetchPosts();
>     }, []);
>
>     console.log(hotVids);
>
>     return(
>         <div>
>             <PopularVid videos={hotVids} loading={loading}/>
>         </div>
>     )
> }
>
> export default PopularApp;
> ```
>
> **PopularVid.js**
>
> ```
> import React from 'react';
>
> const PopularVid = ({videos, loading}) => {
>     if(loading){
>         return <div>Loading...</div>
>     }
>
>     return <ul>
>         {videos.map(video=>(
>             <li key={video.id}>
>                 {video.snippet.title}
>             </li>
>         ))}
>     </ul>;
> }
>
> export default PopularVid;
> ```

And here is the sample of the YouTube json file that I am trying to parse:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "_Y60U4EX77fYwquDNkByKBxEGC8",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "V8SLDA5Sop7jpKOC9NnsckQoOwM",
      "id": "lEIqjoO0-Bs",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-04-29T19:06:00Z",
        "channelId": "UCKrdjiuS66yXOdEZ_cOD_TA",
        "title": "Video #1",
        "description": "This is the description",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lEIqjoO0-Bs/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lEIqjoO0-Bs/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lEIqjoO0-Bs/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lEIqjoO0-Bs/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lEIqjoO0-Bs/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Channel",
        "categoryId": "10",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "4633587",
        "likeCount": "349875",
        "dislikeCount": "6602",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "27237"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "2KGplnTU4KAR0gTjmL8nXnzlK34",
      "id": "XRNjRcKZc1A",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-04-29T16:00:30Z",
        "channelId": "UC47kJWRBD-NREBvmBg5kWeA",
        "title": "Video #2",
        "description": "Description #2",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XRNjRcKZc1A/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XRNjRcKZc1A/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XRNjRcKZc1A/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XRNjRcKZc1A/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XRNjRcKZc1A/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "King Von",
        "categoryId": "10",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "901039",
        "likeCount": "62449",
        "dislikeCount": "1862",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "5184"
      }
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 200,
    "resultsPerPage": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

res.data is an object you can not use map for an object, you can use it for arrays. I believe what you need to map is res.data.items

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured, never would have thought that I need to add `.items` at `res.data` instead of `video.items`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- The initial value of hotVids is undefined. (`[].items`). After the data is fetched it should be OK.
- `loading` is never true. Looks like you meant to set it to true inside `useEffect`. You also could have initialised it to true with useState.

To deal with data that isn’t loaded yet, you’d generally do one of two things: set a reasonable default (like your empty array), which can render successfully; or prevent rendering until loading is done (like your loading variable).

Comment: Yeah, somehow I forgot to set the `loading` to true inside `useEffect`. Thanks a lot!